# Count item corresponding listed Item

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT  a.UPC,COUNT(*)
FROM StoreTransactions a WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN StoreTransactions_Expanded_UOM c
ON a.StoreTransactionID = c.StoreTransactionID
LEFT JOIN ProductCatalog cat
ON a.ProductID = cat.ProductID
LEFT JOIN ProductCatalogBase base
ON cat.ProductCatalogID = base.ProductCatalogID
JOIN ProductIdentifiers d
ON cat.ProductID = d.ProductID AND d.ProductIdentifierTypeID = 2

GROUP BY a.UPC
, d.IdentifierValue, cat.PackDesc, a.ReportedCost, 
base.ManualHigh, base.ManualLow,cat.DateTimeCreated,cat.DateTimeLastUpdate
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```

I want count of UPC corresponding UPC but not getting correct result like below.

```
UPC             Count
071990316006    1463
026565245455    4530
```

Comment: Why are you grouping by all those columns? You should only be grouping by a.UPC. And why NOLOCK? http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: Agree with @SeanLange. If you want just a count of `UPC`, then only `Group By a.UPC`. Remove the other columns in the `Group By`.

Comment: You also `JOIN ProductIdentifiers` with a table that was `LEFT JOIN ProductCatalog cat`. This could give you undetermined results.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to group by a.UPC:

```
SELECT  a.UPC,COUNT(*)
FROM StoreTransactions a WITH (NOLOCK)
JOIN StoreTransactions_Expanded_UOM c
ON a.StoreTransactionID = c.StoreTransactionID
LEFT JOIN ProductCatalog cat
ON a.ProductID = cat.ProductID
LEFT JOIN ProductCatalogBase base
ON cat.ProductCatalogID = base.ProductCatalogID
JOIN ProductIdentifiers d
ON cat.ProductID = d.ProductID AND d.ProductIdentifierTypeID = 2
GROUP BY a.UPC
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```